# node start: Como executar 2 comandos?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon

Quando tento executar o `node start` onde tenho apenas `tsc` ele funciona. Compila corretamente os arquivos TypeScript.

Quando eu tento executar o `node start` onde tenho apenas `nodemon ./dist/app` ele funciona. Executa corretamente o meu app.

O problema está quando eu tento executar o `node start` com o comando `tsc; nodemon ./dist/app`. Gera o erro abaixo:

```
> tsc ; nodemon ./dist/app

error TS6231: Could not resolve the path ';' with the extensions: '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

error TS6231: Could not resolve the path 'dist/app' with the extensions: '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.

error TS6231: Could not resolve the path 'nodemon' with the extensions: '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'. 


Found 3 errors.
```

Comment: Pelo seu código não entendi direito. Você já fez o build e está na pasta `dist` e mesmo assim quer rodar o `tsc` novamente?

Comment: eu quero que sempre que fizer o start, ele rode o tsc e o nodemon

Comment: está rodando em windows? tenta: "start": "tsc && nodemon ./dist/app"